# This error occurred while updating from flutter 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart

The syntax seems to have changed with the update of flutter. I tried to find a solution on the official site, but failed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app1/model/model_member.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Member member;
  DetailScreen({this.member});
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}
```

`Error: The parameter 'member' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Member', but the implicit default value is 'null'.`

and also

```
  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('member').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs);
      },
    );
  }
```

`Error: Property 'docs' cannot be accessed on 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' because it is potentially null.`

Comment: For your first error, do `DetailScreen({required this.member});`. That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Thanks to you, I was able to fix it right away. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("member")
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> chatSnapshot) {
                if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                }
                return ListView(
                  reverse: true,
                  controller: _controller,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  children:
                      chatSnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      return Text(data["name"]);
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Undefined name '_controller'. An error has occurred. What should I do with this?

Comment: you don't need it, remove controller: _controller,

Answer (score 0):

The main change from flutter 1.0 to 2.0 is `Null safety`. So it will make sure that the `member` field is not null. so adding required in front of the `member` should fix the problem

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Member member;
  DetailScreen({required this.member}); // <-- change this line
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}
```